# create .jar empty using bintray upload

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-maven-plugin, bintray

I am newbie to upload module into bintray task, but I sign up bintray accout successfully,I read gradle `bintray-plugin` , I make changes in my `build.gradle`,
package & (lib).jar  created successfully , but (lib).jar is an empty.
   so please help me guys what went wrong in my project.
I did following steps to upload lib yo bintray account after configure build.gradle

1. on terminal run gradlew install it builds successfully.
2. on terminal run gradlew bintray it builds successfully.

project-root `build.gradle` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray"
    version "1.7"
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
}

group = 'com.app.kickdrill'
version = '0.0.1'
```

app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    publishNonDefault true
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-     android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support',
        module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
            name 'KickDrill'
            description 'its for an android developer'
            url 'https://github.com/kickdrilldev/androidkickdrill'
            inceptionYear '2017'
            packaging 'aar'
            groupId 'com.app.kickdrill'
            artifactId 'androidKickdrill'
            version '0.0.1'

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
            scm {
                connection 'https://github.com/kickdrilldev/androidkickdrill.git'
                url 'https://github.com/kickdrilldev/androidkickdrill'

            }
            developers {
                developer {
                    name 'Vyankatesh Jadhav'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



bintray {
    user = project.hasProperty('bintrayUser') ? project.property('bintrayUser') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = project.hasProperty('bintrayApiKey') ? project.property('bintrayApiKey') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'kickdrill'
        name = 'androidkickdrill'
        userOrg = 'androiddevs'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/kickdrilldev/androidkickdrill'
        version {
            name = 'androidKickdrill'
            desc = 'its for an android developer'
            vcsTag = '0.0.1'
            attributes = ['gradle-plugin': 'com.use.less:com.use.less.gradle:gradle-useless-plugin']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `com.android.library` plugin generates an Android archive (AAR) not a Java Archive (JAR).

Also if you want to upload the archive to bintray use the `bintrayUpload` task :

```
./gradlew bintrayUpload
```

Also, in your configuration, you can use `publish = true` if you want your version to be automatically published when uploaded to Bintray :

```
bintray {
    publish = true //If version should be auto published after an upload
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin)

Comment: but bintray upload empty .jar  task